How to filter iOS app version submissions alone from App Store Connect reviewSubmissions REST API?
Using the following App Store Connect REST API to fetch reviewsubmissions of an iOS app.
v1/reviewSubmissions?fields[reviewSubmissionItems]=appStoreVersion,appEvent&filter[app]=<app_id>&include=items,appStoreVersionForReview

Seems like the response included in appEvents submissions as well. How to filter app version submission alone?
Sample response:
{
"data": [
    {
        "type": "reviewSubmissions",
        "id": "3a6b16c5",
        "attributes": {
            "state": "READY_FOR_REVIEW",
            "submittedDate": null,
            "platform": "IOS"
        },
        "relationships": {
            "appStoreVersionForReview": {
                "data": {
                    "type": "appStoreVersions",
                    "id": "110b85d1"
                }
            },
            "items": {
                "meta": {
                    "paging": {
                        "total": 0,
                        "limit": 10
                    }
                },
                "data": [],
            }
        },
    },
    {
        "type": "reviewSubmissions",
        "id": "cbd323ff",
        "attributes": {
            "state": "COMPLETE",
            "submittedDate": "2024-03-12T16:02:15.646Z",
            "platform": "IOS"
        },
        "relationships": {
            "appStoreVersionForReview": {
                "data": {
                    "type": "appStoreVersions",
                    "id": "110b85d1"
                }
            },
            "items": {
                "meta": {
                    "paging": {
                        "total": 1,
                        "limit": 10
                    }
                },
                "data": [
                    {
                        "type": "reviewSubmissionItems",
                        "id": "Y2JkMzI"
                    }
                ],
            }
        },
    },
    {
        "type": "reviewSubmissions",
        "id": "602e1b9d",
        "attributes": {
            "state": "COMPLETE",
            "submittedDate": "2024-03-06T18:24:17.208Z",
            "platform": "IOS"
        },
        "relationships": {
            "appStoreVersionForReview": {
                "data": {
                    "type": "appStoreVersions",
                    "id": "110b85d1"
                }
            },
            "items": {
                "meta": {
                    "paging": {
                        "total": 1,
                        "limit": 10
                    }
                },
                "data": [
                    {
                        "type": "reviewSubmissionItems",
                        "id": "NjAyZTF"
                    }
                ],
            },
      },
   },
],
"included": [
    {
        "type": "appStoreVersions",
        "id": "110b85d1",
        "attributes": {
            "downloadable": true,
            "earliestReleaseDate": null,
            "createdDate": "2024-02-21T11:01:11-08:00",
            "usesIdfa": null,
            "versionString": "2.3.1",
            "releaseType": "AFTER_APPROVAL",
            "appStoreState": "READY_FOR_SALE",
            "reviewType": "APP_STORE",
            "platform": "IOS",
            "appVersionState": "READY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION"
        },
  },
  {
        "type": "appStoreVersions",
        "id": "16eaf328",
        "attributes": {
            "downloadable": true,
            "earliestReleaseDate": null,
            "createdDate": "2023-12-18T07:34:09-08:00",
            "usesIdfa": null,
            "versionString": "1.10.1",
            "releaseType": "AFTER_APPROVAL",
            "appStoreState": "READY_FOR_SALE",
            "reviewType": "APP_STORE",
            "platform": "IOS",
            "appVersionState": "READY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION"
        },
    },
    {
        "type": "reviewSubmissionItems",
        "id": "Y2JkMzI",
    },
    {
        "type": "reviewSubmissionItems",
        "id": "NjAyZTF",
    },
    {
        "type": "reviewSubmissionItems",
        "id": "MDRhM2R",
    }
],

"meta": {
    "paging": {
        "total": 4,
        "limit": 50
    }
}

}
